# server host name and server ip address redirect (Debian, Apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ip-address, hostname

I have the following folder structure on my `Apache`

> .../var/www/www.x.tt/htdocs
>
> .../var/www/www.y.tt/htdocs

I have defined a virtual host for each.

So if I type in `www.x.tt` in my browser I get to the `www.x.tt` site. And the same for `www.y.tt`.

But now my question!
If I type in the server address or the server host name I get to the `../var/www` directory but I want that the user will be redirected to the `www.x.tt` site!

Do I have to create a new virtual host for this problem or is it also possible only to add a `.htaccess` Rule?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention how you configured your virtual hosts, but I guess that you've done it following the "traditional" Debian-way - by creating files in */etc/apache/sites-available/* and then using **a2ensite** to enable the virtual host.

If so, you may edit your */etc/apache/sites-available/default* file and put the virtual host you want to be the default one in it. For example:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ServerName www.x.tt
  ServerAlias x.tt
  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.x.tt/htdocs
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

More information about the [_default_](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default) keyword.

**EDIT :** If you're using name-based virtual hosts, just make sure that the configuration for the *x.tt* vhost is loaded first - this way it will be the default catch-all address.

Comment: `_default_` doesn't do anything when using name-based virtual hosts, just IP-based.  @Matthias, which method are you using?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That was a bad assumption from me. Edited my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You have to user a ServerName and a ServerAlias in your vhost configuration file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName your.domain.com
    ServerAlias your.domain.com www.your.domain.com
```

Otherwise, if you want to have a `default` website for the unspecified vhost, you have to create an vhost for that. You can check that with the command:

```
apache2ctl -S
```

Comment: Javier, I'm pretty sure he's asking about a default catch-all address, so I think the *\_defaut\_* keyword would be more appropriate in this case.